# Flask with Tweepy only pulls the first tweet, need some more tweets

Tags: python, flask, tweepy, jinja2

I am trying to pull a bunch of tweets from a user using Tweepy and Flask. The code looks correct but it only pulls the first tweet and doesn't show the rest. What could be the reason? Tweepy by default should have pulled 20 latest tweets.
Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from jinja2 import Template
import tweepy

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="mytemplate")

t_consumerkey= ''
t_secretkey= ''
access_tokenkey=''
access_tokensecret=''

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', names="John")


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(t_consumerkey, t_secretkey)
auth.set_access_token(access_tokenkey, access_tokensecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.user_timeline(id='california')

@app.route('/twitter')
def twitterdisplayer():
    for tweet in public_tweets:
        return tweet.text

if(__name__) == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

PS, I know this may look like a poorly written code because I am a beginner to programming. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `twitterdisplayer()` you are looping through the list of tweets but returning the first one. A function stops executing on the `return` keyword.

Try this:

```
def twitterdisplayer():
    all_tweets_text = []
    for tweet in public_tweets:
        all_tweets_text.append(tweet.text)
    return all_tweets_text
```